# Ethics of upvoting own answer.

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that a lot of brand new answers have already been upvoted by the time I get to reading them (presumably by the author of said answer). I have not been upvoting my own answers. Unfortunately as a result (perhaps because the question asker hasn't gotten around to reading through answers) I have a few answers with a score of 0.

What are the 'ethics' of "seeding" your own answer with an upvote? (Also: am I mistaken that you are capable of upvoting your own answer?) Finally, if you can upvote your own answer, why would you ever NOT upvote your answer (outside of general humbleness) - presumably you think the answer is good because you bothered to invest the time in writing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't upvote your own answer or question. (Try it, you'll get a message that explains it.)

Comment: Oh, that resolves all of my questions then. How silly of me.

Comment: Someone who is really desperate could register a shill to vote on their contributions.  However, this would be easy to detect by the system, and seems like a poor use of time.