# Better name for the so-called “top-level tags”

Tags: discussion, tags

It is [recommended](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/using-at-least-one-top-level-arxiv-tag) to tag every question with at least one in the (vaguely recognized) set of tags that represent the subject areas of questions.  These tags are sometimes referred to as “top-level tags,” but I would like to change this name if there is a better name.

The word “top-level” implies existence of a hierarchical structure.  Since most tags are not part of any hierarchical structure, the word “top-level” does not make much sense.

Does anyone have an idea what they should be called?

---

*Update*: Let’s call them “area tags.”  (Thanks to Kaveh for proposing this name.)  It is a concise name which describes their nature pretty accurately.

Comment: super-tag, main-tag, area-tag, subject-classification-tag, primary-tag, primary-subject-classification-tag, ...

Comment: "Required tag"?

Comment: @Kaveh: Some of the suggestions are good, others are too long.

Comment: @Jukka: “Required tag” is not a very good name, because it is the official term to refer to a tag on meta that is really required by the system (a question cannot be posted on meta if it does not have any required tag), namely one of the tags [discussion], [bug], [support] and [feature-request].  See the legend on the [tags page on meta](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags).  “Recommended tag” may be better.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Well, we can decide that they *are* required. And we can pretend that the fact that the system doesn't actually enforce it is just a fairly harmless bug.

Comment: @Jukka: The point is that we may have to distinguish these tags from the tags required by the system, especially when we talk about the system.  I would not like a feature request titled “Make required tags really required.”

Comment: Yet another suggestion (similar to @Kaveh's area-tag): "subfield tag".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kaveh and Jukka posted several suggestions as comments (why not answers?).  Among them, I like “area tag” the best because it is concise and describes what it is about.  “Subfield tag” is another good name.

Unless a much better name comes up later, I propose to call these tags “area tags.”

Comment: *"why not answers?"* – Answers can be down-voted, but comments can be only up-voted! You cannot lose!

Comment: I second "area tag"

Comment: I posted them in a comment because it was quicker and they were just suggestions that came to my mind when I read your question, I also would need to post them separately if I wanted to post them as answers.