# Use a consistent prefix to distinguish area tags instead of CoRR subject area codes

Tags: discussion, tags

This is a continuation of a discussion which took place in comments on [this post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/computability-behaves-like-a-top-level-tag/1006#1006).

It is [recommended](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/using-at-least-one-top-level-arxiv-tag) to tag every question with at least one **area tag** ([formerly called “top-level tag”](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/better-name-for-the-so-called-top-level-tags)).  Currently area tags are named in the following way:

- The area tags which originate from [CoRR subject areas](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses) are named as `xx.description` where `xx` is the coresponding CoRR subject area codes and `description` is the descriptive name of the area.  Examples are [cr.crypto-security](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cr.crypto-security), [cg.comp-geom](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cg.comp-geom), [ds.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms) and [ds.data-structures](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.data-structures).  Note that some area tags deviate from the categorization in CoRR.
- The other area tags are labeled like usual tags.  Examples are [computability](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability) and [quantum-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing).

There are two problems with the current area tags.

- Names depend on whether they originate from CoRR subject areas or not, which is not an important distinction.  Therefore tags look simply inconsistent.
- There is no advantage of having the corresponding CoRR subject area codes in the tags.  As I understand it, the only purpose of these codes is to indicate that they are area tags.  However, this is incomplete because not every area tag has a two-letter code.

I think that a more consistent naming is better.

If the Stack Exchange server had a functionality of showing area tags in a different color, we would not have to distinguish them by names.  Because it does not have such a functionality, it is better to distinguish area tags by names.

Therefore, I propose the following:

**Proposal**.  Remove the `xx.` part from the area tags of the form `xx.description` and instead add a fixed prefix to all the area tags.  As the fixed prefix, I suggest to use either `a.` (for “area”) or just `.`.  [*Edit*: I removed the earlier suggestions `a:` and `:` because it turned out that a colon cannot be used in tags.]

Comment: I'd vote for either a. or area. as a prefix. I suspect area. would be a problem because it's too long, though.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the comment.  As you guessed, I wrote `a.` instead of `area.` because I thought that `area.` might be too long.

Comment: the `a.` is very cryptic. Can tags be made case-sensitive ? that would be an option then.

Comment: It seems that we can't have upper-case tags. And we can't have tags that begin with a "#".

Comment: @Suresh: It is funny that you think that `a.` is very cryptic while you do not complain the same thing to the current subject area codes, which are equally cryptic (I really do not buy the argument that TCS researchers are familiar with CoRR codes).  The point is that we lose nothing if we replace the two-letter codes by a fixed prefix, and a fixed prefix is more consistent.

Comment: I created two answers with the two proposals, "a.something" and ".something"; please up/downvote your favourite. Personally I think "a.something" is cryptic, and I would strongly prefer ".something" (but can't upvote my own answers...).

Comment: @Jukka: I consider that which prefix to use is a secondary issue.  If we can agree that we should use a common prefix, I do not care much what the prefix is, as long as it is not too long.  (If I had cared, I would have checked which characters are accepted as tags by myself….)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Actually I think TCS researchers are more and more familiar with CoRR codes, based on the increased frequency of publication in the arxiv: see for example http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/are-open-tech-report-sites-taking-off.html

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks for the interesting stats.  I take back the claim that TCS researchers are not familiar with CoRR codes.  Still I do not see what we gain by adding the codes to tags.  [ds.algorithms] and [algorithms] are equally understandable.

Comment: there's something stunningly hideous about the proposed tags (either the a.* or the .* variants). I wouldn't have minded area.*: is length really an issue ? after all we already have [tag:cg.comp-geom]

Comment: @Suresh: Now I am not sure if `area.` is too long.  Maybe it is not.

Comment: I like the idea, the nice thing about having a simple recognizable structure is that we can write user scripts to show the tags the way we like, e.g. in a similar way to papers: (primary and secondary) subject classification in one place using one color and keywords in another place using a different color. It seems that the only symbols that we can use for tags are: "+", "#", "-", ".". The system acts strangely regarding "#", and "-" can be confusing considering its other use.

Comment: I don't like `a.xxxx` and `.xxxx`, would prefer to use 'subject' or 'sc' (subject classification) in place of 'area', but 'area' is also good if we are worried about the length restrictions. (Does anyone know why the system acts strangely  about having # at the beginning of tag?)

Comment: @Kaveh: If we call them area tags, then the prefix `area` makes more sense than `subject` or `sc`.  But I really think that which prefix to use is a secondary issue at this moment.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I agree that is a secondary issue. :) (The reason I prefer `subject` to `area` is that `subject classification` (e.g. CoRR, AMS-MSC) is what is used for classifying papers, though ACM calls its system Computing Classification System.)

Comment: On a second thought, I now think `.xxxx` looks good if we are going to use "." consistently and only for this purpose.

Comment: @Kaveh: I think the system is designed so that you can have tags for programming languages such as .NET, C++, and C#. That's why you can't use . in the end or # in the beginning, as there is no programming language that requires it.

Comment: @Kaveh: And yes, the idea would be to use "." consistently and only for this purpose. Otherwise the proposal makes little sense.

Comment: Considering the number of down votes on answers so far, I think it is going to be difficult to reach consensus.

Comment: @Kaveh: I am more interested in the votes on the proposal itself, which is +3 −1 now.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to write some CSS code that recognises the area tags, highlights them, and removes the area-tag prefix? Can CSS depend on the content of the HTML element?

Comment: @Jukka: With a user script, it must be possible.  In CSS 2.1, it is not possible to apply styles depending on the content of an element, but it might be possible to use the href attribute of the <a> element in this case.

Comment: yes, with a user script it should be fairly easy to do

Comment: A user script does not help *all* users of the site. I was wondering if the SE admins could just slightly tweak CSS for us (I guess tweaking the engine would be a much bigger problem).

Comment: @Jukka: The href hack I suggested is also almost impossible, at least within the standard CSS 2.1.  The exception is when the fixed prefix ends with `-`.  For example, if the prefix is `area-`, then we can select the <a> elements representing those tags by using the CSS selector `a[href|="/questions/tagged/area"]` (see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) for why this works).  But I do not think that we can hide the `area-` part (nor do I think that it is good to hide it), and moreover I doubt that the admins are happy to use a hack like this.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi and @all: It seems that none of the ideas proposed are ideal (since all of them got zero points or less), so what should we do? Personally I think any proposal here is better than the current tagging scheme, and now [.xxxx] and [area.xxxx] are in a tie, with [+3/-3] and [+2/-2] votes.

Answer (score 4):

Please keep in mind the following aspects:

- One of the tags appears in the page title (and hence also in Google search results). The logic seems to be the following: take the most common (least specific...) tag and replace each dash with a space. The end result is something like this with the current tags:

  > cc.complexity theory - Problems Between P and NPC - Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange
- The maximum length of a tag is 25 characters. For example, these should be fine (just some hypothetical examples to illustrate the limitations):

  [subject.quantum-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject.quantum-computing)
  [subject.history-overview](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject.history-overview)
  [subject.programming-lang](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject.programming-lang)
  [pl.programming-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pl.programming-languages)
  [dc.distributed-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc.distributed-computing)
  [a.programming-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.programming-languages)
  [a.distributed-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.distributed-computing)
  [a.artificial-intelligence](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.artificial-intelligence)
  [.approximation-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.approximation-algorithms)
  [.communication-complexity](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.communication-complexity)
  [automated-theorem-proving](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automated-theorem-proving)

  These would be a bit too long:

  [area.distributed-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area.distributed-computing)
  [area.programming-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area.programming-languages)
  [ai.artificial-intelligence](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intelligence)
  [a.approximation-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.approximation-algorithms)
  [a.communication-complexity](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.communication-complexity)
  [.automated-theorem-proving](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.automated-theorem-proving)

**Edit:**

- Yet another place where it matters what our area tags look like: the new https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users page.

Comment: AFAIK, the last three tags are not area tags (this is one of the reasons I prefer calling the former top-level tags "subject (classification) tags" to "area tag", since calling the area tags can be misleading).

Comment: [area.artificial-intel], [area.distributed-comput], [area.programming-lang] are all perfectly understandable, if somewhat ugly.

Comment: @Kaveh: they are *just examples*. I just wanted to show what kind of compounds would be too long and what are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Proposal 2: [.xxxx](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.xxxx) like: [.crypto-security](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.crypto-security), [.comp-geom](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.comp-geom), [.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.algorithms), [.computability](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.computability), [.quantum-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.quantum-computing), ...

Comment: This format is good: it is short, it is not confusing, and the system supports it. It might not be very nice but using user-scripts we should be able to show these tags the way we like. So this is my favorite.

Comment: Please add a comment if you are down voting an answer.

Comment: I like [area.xxxx] better; this is too cryptic.

Comment: I wonder what makes this "cryptic". Many people might not even notice the dots. In my opinion, this would be best because it is by far the least distracting. Area tags are also the most popular tags, they are displayed in many places (e.g. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users), and any extra prefix will make the pages look busier.

Comment: You have a point. I retract my objection.

Answer (score 0):

Proposal: [area.xxxx](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area.xxxx) like [area.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area.algorithms), [area.data-structures](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area.data-structures)

Answer (score -2):

Proposal 4: [subject.xxxx](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject.xxxx)

Comment: This is horribly long. Besides, tags have limited length (25 characters).

Comment: @Jukka, it was a suggestion but now I agree with you.

Answer (score -5):

Proposal 1: [a.xxxx](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.xxxx) like [a.crypto-security](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.crypto-security), [a.comp-geom](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.comp-geom), [a.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.algorithms), [a.computability](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.computability), [a.quantum-computing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.quantum-computing), ...

Comment: Again, this is too cryptic; I like [area.xxxx] better