# What does “closed as off topic” mean?

Tags: support, faq, closing, close-reasons

What does the following message mean?

> closed as off topic by [Someone], [Someone], [Someone], [Someone], [Someone] [Date]
>
> Questions on Theoretical Computer Science are expected to generally relate to Theoretical Computer Science, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: tsuyoshi, why did you create this question ? is this part of the FAQ ? if so, why not just add it in there ?

Comment: @Suresh: (1) The FAQ page is already too crowded.  I think that putting too many things makes it hard to maintain.  (2) I wanted to include the boilerplate message in the question.  I cannot do this in the FAQ page.

Comment: then maybe add a link from there to here ?

Comment: @Suresh: That is fine, but I believe that the [faq] tag is exactly for that purpose.  If the consensus is that we should consider a question as an FAQ, moderators can add the [faq] tag and the [list of questions tagged as faq](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) serves as the list of FAQ.  That is how things are supposed to work as I understand it.

Comment: these are not exclusive. The reason we had a single "question" was so that there was a single place to list questions. I don't think the question itself is that clustered.

Comment: @Suresh: Added a link from there to here.  BTW, it seems like we should have used chat for this!  (I cannot participate in a chat right now, sorry.)

Comment: indeed. that would have been a good use of chat.

Answer (score 1):

When a question is closed, no additional answers may be posted to it.  A user who votes to close a question must select one of the following reasons:

- Exact duplicate
- Off topic
- Belongs to meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com
- Subjective and argumentative
- Not a real question
- Too localized

Since questions on cstheory.stackexchange.com are expected to be research-level questions in theoretical computer science, “off topic” means anything that fails to satisfy this criterion.

Even a question in theoretical computer science will be considered as off topic if, for example, it is too basic to be research-level.  **Forget about the system-generated boilerplate message.**

A question being closed as off topic means that the question does not belong to cstheory.stackexchange.com.  It does not necessarily mean that the question is bad.  For example, a question about programming (actually writing code) will be probably closed as off topic on cstheory.stackexchange.com even if it is very interesting.

For general information about closed questions and the meanings of other close reasons on Stack Exchange websites, please refer to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Related:

- [My (wonderful!) question was closed! What do I do now?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/361#361)
- [What kind of questions are too basic?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/235#235)
- Other discussions/questions posted on meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com about the [scope of cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)