# Non-meta, related discussions in parent site

Tags: discussion, questions

I have just open a question about [More on syntactic vs semantic classes, and UP vs NP](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/more-on-syntactic-vs-semantic-classes-and-up-vs-np). In the comments, @Tsuyoshi and I were discussing whether my interpretation about a related result to the problems is correct or not. As he said, this discussion is not directly related to the main questions, and by his word *"this is kind of off topic here"*, and I agree.

Since the discussion is all about related results and not about the site, I see [no reasons](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) to put the discussions here in meta. But staying in the same question may be improper too. So what should I do if I would like to continue the discussion? Should I open a new topic just about interpreting the related result? Is that off-topic in TCS SE? (Since SE sites [discourage discussions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/302#302).)

Comment: You can use chat. :)

Comment: Contact the user privately?

Comment: I've heard email can be quite handy :)

Comment: I'll ask @Tsuyoshi privately to see if he is willing to, since I do not want to disturb him if emails are too "private". It is interesting that people (that is, me) always forget the most obvious way to get things done :) Thank you all very much!!

Answer (score 6):

So you wrote me an email and I replied you, suggesting you to post a new question on cstheory.stackexchange.com.  I hope that you can distill a concrete question out of it.  :)

Let me write how I feel about continuing a conversation on this website in email.

First of all, I appreciate the fact that you were very considerate in writing to me personally.  I do not mind receiving an email like yours occasionally.

That said, in general, I do not want to continue a conversation on this website in email, unless the subject is so close to my interest that I want to spend more time on it.

There are topics which I really care about, topics which I am somewhat interested in, and topics which I am not at all interested in.  When I write something on this website, I am usually *somewhat interested* in the subject but I am not willing to commit myself into the subject.  In such a case, a conversation on a website is fine, but a private conversation by email is, well, too private.  For example, even if I write something incorrect, there are no experts who can correct me.  So I have to think much more carefully in private conversations.  And I cannot spend much time on the subject in which I am only *somewhat interested*.

All of this is my personal opinion/feeling and by no means universal.  Some people probably like private discussions on topics in which they are marginally interested.  Also, my feeling is not solid and may change easily.

I hope I did not harm your feelings.

Comment: Not at all, your replies and suggestions are nice, and I am really thankful to your help. And you are right, there are a lot of experts here who can give ideas and correct the discussion if needed, that is what a public Q&A site like TCS SE for. Like what I said in the letter, I'll think more about my question, and post a new question on that topic without being like a discussion one, which is off-topic here.